# Weighting a survey variable in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Firstly, I couldn't find a package that weights survey variables in python, is there one available (in R I use wtd.table)?

I've create a workaround by manipulating the variable that I want to weight and multiplying it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Data_2017_18.income.value_counts()

0      29212
100       95

income_Data_2017_18.income2 = Data_NVF_2017_18.income/100

income_Data_2017_18.income2.value_counts()

0.0    29212
1.0       95

income_Data_2017_18.income2_weight = income_Data_2017_18.income2 * income_Data_2017_18.surveyweight

np.sum(income_Data_2017_18.income2_weight)

168744.20141431427
```

The output is correct but are there any suggestions on whether this can be improved, please?

Much appreciated.

Comment: what improvement are you thinking about? what is bothering you?

Comment: I was wondering whether this was the most efficient way of doing it...